# Update and On_Draw Pyglet in Thread

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.7, pyglet

I wanted to ask, is it possible to put the Update and On_Draw functions of a Pyglet class created by the user in a thread? Let me explain. I have the class of my app of Pyglet, in which I need some functions (always of the same class) that work simultaneously with the Update and On_Draw functions. Now, I've been looking around and the only things I've found is inserting the entire Pyglet app into a main thread, but doing so would give problems to the Pyglet itself. I just need to have those two functions in one main thread and the other functions in secondary threads. It's possible to do it?

EDIT:

With a few tries, since this is the first time I've used threads, I've managed to put together a script that works.

```
from pyglet.gl import *
from pyglet.window import FPSDisplay
import threading, time, os

FPS = 120.0

class test(pyglet.window.Window):

    loop = True
    th = True
    load = 10

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__video_set()
        self.label = pyglet.text.Label(('LOADING: '+str((self.load-10)//10)+"%"), font_name='Times New Roman', font_size=36)
        self.label.x = self.width // 2
        self.label.y = self.height // 2 + 200
        self.thread = threading.Thread(target=self.loader)
        self.thread.start()

    def loader(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        while self.loop is True:
            time.sleep(0.05)
            if self.load >= 1010:
                self.loop = False
            else:
                self.load += 1

    def on_draw(self):
        self.clear()
        self.bar = pyglet.graphics.draw(2, pyglet.gl.GL_LINES, ('v2i', (10, 250, int(self.load), 250)))
        self.bar = pyglet.gl.glLineWidth(20)
        if self.load >= 15:
            self.label.draw()

    def update(self, dt):
        if self.load >= 1010:
            self.label.text = ("LOADING COMPLETE")
        else:
            self.label.text = ("LOADING: "+str((self.load-10)//10)+"%")

    def on_close(self):
        self.close()
        os._exit(0)

    def __video_set(self):
        self.__platform = pyglet.window.get_platform()
        self.__default_display = self.__platform.get_default_display()
        self.__default_screen = self.__default_display.get_default_screen()
        self.__default_dimension_screen = 1024, 576

        self.set_size(self.__default_dimension_screen[0], self.__default_dimension_screen[1])
        self.location = self.__default_screen.width // 2 - self.__default_dimension_screen[0] // 2, self.__default_screen.height // 2 - self.__default_dimension_screen[1] // 2
        self.set_location(self.location[0], self.location[1])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ts = test()
    pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(ts.update, 1 / FPS)
    pyglet.app.run()
```

This script simulates an initial load, with a loading bar and a percentage that shows loading. A thread is opened in which there is a `while` cycle which simulates the loading and every time it cycles, it modifies the `self.load` variable. Since this is the first time I get my hands on the threads, is the work I've done right? Also, I would like to ask, in the thread function, I was forced to insert two `time.sleep`. This is because no matter where I put it, if in the `__init__` function, or in the `update` or other function, the thread was too fast and ended either before the window was created, or the loading bar went from 0 to 100 in less than a second. Is there a solution without having to use `time.sleep`?

Comment: Short answer is, no. That will cause a segfault. You won't be able to do any `GL` operations from secondary threads. You can however influence a pyglet class variables, just don't touch the GL context. So creating a main class with Pyglet, and update any variable within that class from a thread - is possible. And your `on_draw` can check variables and act accordingly.

Comment: But in the secondary thread I wouldn't need GL. To make it simple, in the main thread imagine a loading bar that is updated by a variable "x" and then drawn using the Update and On_Draw functions. In the secondary thread, on the other hand, the various operations or calculations are performed and each time you complete something, you change the "x" variable. To do this, the functions must work simultaneously. Otherwise, before the Update and On_Draw functions that update the loading bar are called, the secondary function must terminate completely, rendering the entire initial intention vain.

Comment: I don't know if I explained myself well enough, given my poor English XD

Comment: That you can do. As long as you don't fiddle directly with the variables during the rendering process. Use locks and buffers between the two threads to achieve this. And post the code above when you have something. But yes, that would work.

Comment: Added a test script :)