# Is there a faster way to draw on screen using pyglet and threading?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyglet, concurrent.futures

The three functions below show how I'm using the pyglet library to draw squares on the screen. The code works fine. But I want to make it run faster.

With my novice understanding of threading, I think the for-loop in `draw_grid()` can be made faster by using threads, as it waits for one square to draw using `pos` and then draws a new square. Since `all_positions` is already provided, is there a way to draw all squares simultaneously?

```
def draw_square(single_location):
    # draws a single square
    pyglet.graphics.draw_indexed(4, pyglet.graphics.gl.GL_TRIANGLES,
                             [0,1,2,1,2,3],
                             ('v2i', single_location))

def position_array():
    # returns an 2D array with each row representing the coordinates of the rectangle to draw
    ...relevant code...
    return all_positions

def draw_grid(all_positions):
    # uses draw_square function and all_positions to draw multiple squares at the specified locations.
    for pos in all_positions:
        draw_square(pos)
```

After looking up some videos on threading, I found the `concurrent.futures` library. So I tried to implement it and it gave me errors. So now I am stuck.

Here's how I used `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()` inside `draw_grid()`

```
def draw_grid(all_positions):
    # uses draw_square function and all_positions to draw multiple squares at the specified locations.
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor as executor:
        for pos in all_positions:
        f1 = executor.submit(draw_square, pos)
        f1.result()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a general rule, never mix threads and graphical rendering. It is a recepie for disaster. It is possible to utilize threads in combination with rendering (GL). But again, **it's not recommended**.

Instead, what you probably want to have a look at is batched rendering.
There's great [documentation on Batched rendering](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/programming_guide/graphics.html#batched-rendering) which you'll probably find easy to understand.

Just remember that, if you want to modify the vertices after adding them to a patch, you need to store them and modify the return from the batch, don't try to manipulate the batch directly.

```
vertex_list = batch.add(2, pyglet.gl.GL_POINTS, None,
    ('v2i', (10, 15, 30, 35)),
    ('c3B', (0, 0, 255, 0, 255, 0))
)
# vertex_list.vertices <-- Modify here
```

The reason for why you don't want to use threads, is that there's almost a 99.9% guarantee that you'll end up with a segmentation fault due to a race condition. Where something is trying to update the screen while you're rendering the things you're trying to manipulate.

More info in the comments here: [Update and On_Draw Pyglet in Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55128117/update-and-on-draw-pyglet-in-thread)

So instead, add all your squares to one batch, and do `batch.draw()` and it will simulatainiously draw all squares in one pass. Instead of wasting CPU cycles calling functions and re-create the squares each time and then render them one by one.

```
batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
batch.add(2, pyglet.gl.GL_TRIANGLES, None,
    ('v2i', [0,1,2,1,2,3])
)

def on_draw():
    batch.draw()
```

Something along the lines of this. But obviously you'd wanat to create squares in different positions etc. But as a guideline, create the batch and the squares outside the rendering logic, and then call `.draw()` on the batch in the render cycle.